# The Reversal Game - Scoring permutations using prefix reversals in order to generate only the highest scoring permutations

Tags: permutation, reverse, prefix

I am trying to create a "prefix reversal game" which generates only the permutations from n=2 (ie: {1,2}, {2,1}) to n=100, that require the highest number of prefix reversals in order to replace one at the beginning of the permutation.

For example,

- {2, 4, 1, 3} (the first two elements reverse) -->
- {4, 2, 1, 3} (the first four elements reverse) -->
- {2, 1, 3, 4} (the first two elements reverse) -->
- {1, 2, 3, 4} (end).

Therefore this permutation has a score of "4".

The part that I am having problems with is creating and implementing my own algorithm in order to find the highest scoring permutations without having to test every single one (because it is very inefficient). I was wondering if anybody could offer assistance in creating this algorithm.

I have been looking at algorithms such as the "pancake sorting" algorithm, but this seems to be the opposite of what I want.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: I don't have any code for this yet, it's all just in theory. I don't quite know where to start.

Comment: 4213 reversed is 3124 in my universe.